# fast export from Teradata using Python

Tags: python, teradata

We are trying to export data from Teradata using Python but when we used {fn teradata_sessions(4)}{fn teradata_require_fastexport}select * from table1; it's not triggereing fast export in Teradata and its going as normal select.How to use fast export from teradata using python and here i can't increase more than 4 session too.Could anyone have used fastexport in python for exporting data from Teradata and then copying into dataframe ...then converting to CSV file or any exporting into CSV file from python from Teradata also welcome.

Comment: What version of `teradatasql` package? Needs to be 17.0.0.7 or later. Teradata has a `CSV` table function that can do conversion on the database side as part of the SELECT, rather than doing conversion on client side.

Comment: 17.10.0.1 we are using and we want to do fast export from a table ...since 1Million records taking 6-7 mins ..can you give example on the csv export by a select

Comment: @LeslyPremsinghC did you any solution ? Even I am searching for the same. If you get can you please share sample code for our reference. It would be helpful to all of us.